# Get value from percentile

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table called `count` that has about a million rows. How do I find a value corresponding to a percentile value on a specific column called `units` (with null values)? For example, if I set the percentile = 0.85, I should receive a value of 5000 from the column `units`.

This is what I tried, but the result is a double precision value instead of just an integer and I also can't verify if the result is correct, as it also returns a relatively small number while the largest value of the column is a few times higher, which is suspicious:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.85) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY units) AS percentile
FROM count WHERE units IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: "I also can't verify if the result is correct"  So what are we supposed to do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get the number `CROSS JOIN`the result and compare the columns

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.85) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY units) AS percentile
FROM count WHERE units IS NOT NULL)
  SELECT * FROM count CROSS JOIN CTE WHERE CTE.percentile = count.units OR (percentile IS NULL AND  count.units IS NULL);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W7IZjfw3)